# Java 8 - Count of words and then arrange in desc order

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a list of words, say

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("Hello alan i am here where are you"+  
  "and what are you doing hello are you there");
```

How can I get the top seven words which are repeated more than once in the list in descending order? And then the single entry words should be arranged in alphabetical order. So the output for the above should be those top seven words

```
you (3)
are (2)
hello (2)
alan (1)
am (1)
and (1)
doing (1)
```

I am looking this to do in Java 8 using streams, lamda.

I am trying in this way.
First sort the list
Second get the map of words with its count of words in the list of words.

```
List<String> sortedWords = Arrays.asList("Hello alan i am here where are you and what are you doing hello you there".split(" "))
            .stream().sorted().collect(toList());

Map<String, Long> collect = 
            sortedWords.stream().collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most difficult part is the sorting. Since you want to keep only the 7 first elements from the result and you want to sort the Map by its values, we need to create a Map of all the result, sort it and then keep the 7 results.

In the following code, every word is lower-cased and grouped by themselves, counting the number of occurences. Then, we need to sort this map so we create a Stream over the entries, sort them according to the values (in descending order) and then according to the keys. The 7 first elements are retained, mapped to their key (which correspond to the word) and collected into a `List`, thus keeping encounter order.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence = "Hello alan i am here where are you and what are you doing hello are you there";
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList(sentence.split(" "));

    List<String> result = 
            words.stream()
                 .map(String::toLowerCase)
                 .collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting()))
                 .entrySet().stream()
                 .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long> comparingByValue(reverseOrder()).thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
                 .limit(7)
                 .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                 .collect(toList());

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output:

```
[are, you, hello, alan, am, and, doing]
```

*Note that you made a mistake in your wanted output: `"are"` actually appears 3 times like `"you"` so it should be before*

NB: this code assumes a lot of static imports, namely:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.reverseOrder;
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
```

Comment: My preference here would be to make this two explicit stream pipelines, rather than doing .entrySet().stream() in the "middle", because it makes it more clear what's actually going on -- that you're performing two distinct stream operations.  This enhances readability without having any runtime cost.  (More generally, while method chaining is cook, it can easily be overdone -- just because you can chain, doesn't mean you have to do it all the time.)

Comment: @Brain, i will take this, as it will be more readable as said

Answer (score 4):

While @Tunaki solution is great, it's interesting that using [my StreamEx library](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex), it's possible to solve the problem in single Stream pipeline (no actual operation will be performed until the single terminal operation is called):

```
Map<String, Long> map = StreamEx.of(words)
    .map(String::toLowerCase)
    .sorted() // sort original words, so now repeating words are next to each other
    .runLengths() // StreamEx feature: squash repeating words into Entry<String, Long>
    .sorted(Entry.<String, Long> comparingByValue().reversed()
                 .thenComparing(Entry.comparingByKey()))
    .limit(7) // Sort and limit
    .toCustomMap(LinkedHashMap::new); // Single terminal operation: store to LinkedHashMap
```

Or if only words are needed:

```
List<String> list =StreamEx.of(words)
    .map(String::toLowerCase)
    .sorted() // sort original words, so now repeating words are next to each other
    .runLengths() // StreamEx feature: squash repeating words into Entry<String, Long>
    .sorted(Entry.<String, Long> comparingByValue().reversed()
                 .thenComparing(Entry.comparingByKey()))
    .limit(7) // Sort and limit
    .keys() // Drop counts leaving only words
    .toList(); // Single terminal operation: store to List
```

Comment: The more I read your answers, the more I believe your StreamEx library is what should be in the API in the first place!

Comment: @Tagir, great, i will check your StreamEx.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the best solution to a problem is not an algorithm, but a data structure.  I think what you need here is a Bag.  Since you want the output sorted by occurrences and then by key, the specific data structure you should use is a `TreeBag`.  The following code will work using [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) with Java 8 Streams:

```
String string =
    "Hello alan i am here where are you and what are you doing hello are you there";
List<ObjectIntPair<String>> pairs =
    Stream.of(string.toLowerCase().split(" "))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeBag::new))
        .topOccurrences(7);
System.out.println(pairs);
```

This code will output:

```
// Strings with occurrences
[are:3, you:3, hello:2, alan:1, am:1, and:1, doing:1, here:1, i:1, there:1, what:1, where:1]
```

The `topOccurrences()` method has logic to deal with ties, which basically leaves it to the developer to determine how they want to handle situations with ties.  If you want exactly the first seven items from this list, you could then chain a call to `.take(7);`

The code can also be further simplified to:

```
List<ObjectIntPair<String>> pairs =
    TreeBag.newBagWith(string.split(" ")).topOccurrences(7);
System.out.println(pairs);
```

The static factory method `TreeBag.newBagWith()` accepts a vararg argument so you can just pass the result of `String.split()` directly to it.

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a simple person, so I'd use a `Map<String, Integer>` to count each word first.
Then create a `TreeSet` for each of the counts, and store those in a `TreeMap<Integer, TreeSet>`. Should be rather straightforward from there.

Answer (score 0):

Two-step solution: **group/count**, then **process by count descending**

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("Hello alan i am here where are you and what are you doing hello you there".split(" "));

Map<String, Long> collect = words.stream()
        .map(String::toLowerCase) // convert to lower case
        .collect( // group and count by name
                Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

collect.keySet().stream()
        .sorted( // order by count descending, then by name
                Comparator
                        .comparing(collect::get)
                        .reversed()
                        .thenComparing(Collator.getInstance()))
        .map(k -> k + " (" + collect.get(k) + ")") // map to name and count string
        .limit(7) // only first 7 entries
        .forEach(System.out::println); // output
```