# Count occurrences of a String in a List, then sort the result - Java 8

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I see there are many flavors of this "count occurrences and sort" type of questions (the closest related question was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855363/java-8-count-of-words-and-then-arrange-in-desc-order)) but none of them are working in my situation.

This is my code.

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

Employee e1 = new Employee;
e1.setFirstName("Beth");

Employee e2 = new Employee;
e1.setFirstName("Beth");

Employee e3 = new Employee;
e1.setFirstName("Andrew");

// similarly I'm creating millions of employees and adding them to my list below 

employees.add(e1);
employees.add(e2);
employees.add(e3);
employees.add(e53456667);

//count occurrences of first names
Map<String, Long> employeeFirstNameCount = employees.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getFirstName(), Collectors.counting()));
```

This results in

```
{Beth=2, Andrew=34674, Charles=2388491, John=223545, Alex=2345562}
```

But I need it as

```
{Alex=2345562, Andrew=34674, Beth=2, Charles=2388491, John=223545}
```

I tried this [(reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855363/java-8-count-of-words-and-then-arrange-in-desc-order)):

```
Map<String, Long> employeeFirstNameCount = employees.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getFirstName(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long> comparingByValue(Comparator.naturalOrder()).thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
        .limit(20)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(toList());
```

But getting this error

[image]

Now I am clueless. Can someone please help?

Comment: You are making a `List` with `toList()` but you are assigning to variable declared as `Map<String, Long>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the desired output if you use a `TreeMap` instead of the default `HashMap` when you create the `Map` like this:

```
Map<String, Long> employeeFirstNameCount = employees.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getFirstName,
                                           TreeMap::new,
                                           Collectors.counting()));
```

The `java.util.TreeMap` uses the natural ordering of its keys (that is enough for what you need) or you can provide a custom `Comparator`

Note I use the lambda expression `Employee::getFirstName` instead of `p -> p.getFirstName()`, but both produce the same result.

Comment: Adding TreeMap did change order of some names but the order is still unsorted.

Comment: The TreeMap sorts by the key, and since repeated keys can not exist, there is no need to sort by value. The methods keySet(), values(), toString(), entrySet() all return sorted-by-key results

Comment: I figured out why I wasn't seeing the sorted result. After the Map is created from your code, I was doing `new JSONObject(employeeFirstNameCount ).toString(2)` to see the result properly. That's messing up the order again but during debug I confirmed the values in `employeeFirstNameCount` are actually sorted. I tried yours as well as @Aomine's solutions and both worked great. Thanks for your help!

Comment: By the way, I am keeping p -> p.getFirstName. and using your solution because it's shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the result as `Map<String, Long>`, you should not map to the entry key i.e. `.map(Map.Entry::getKey)` as we well as that you should not collect to a list either, i.e. `.collect(toList())` as eventually you'll end up with `List<String>` instead of `Map<String, Long>`, rather after sorting by the specified criteria, you should collect to a map and in particular a `LinkedHashMap`:

```
Map<String, Long> result = employees.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getFirstName(), 
                           Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long> comparingByKey())
                .limit(20)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                    Map.Entry::getValue, 
                    (l,r) -> l, 
                    LinkedHashMap::new));
```

The comparator above will sort by key only as that's what your expected result seems to suggest.

---

Note that if you don't need the `limit` operation after grouping the above can be simplified to:

```
employees.stream()
         .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getFirstName))
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getFirstName,
                        LinkedHashMap::new,
                        Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: I tried your code. The error I was having went away but the results are still unsorted. :(

Comment: @AMagic see edit. I've changed the comparator based on the expected result. if you're still not getting what you require then consider saying exactly what you want to sort by... i.e. by value then by key? by value descending then by key....?

Comment: I figured out why I wasn't seeing the sorted result. After the Map is created from your code, I was doing `new JSONObject(employeeFirstNameCount ).toString(2)` to see the result properly. That's messing up the order again but during debug I confirmed the values in `employeeFirstNameCount` are actually sorted. I tried yours as well as @DSantiagoBC's solutions and both worked great. Thanks for your help!